# Asynchronous encryption/decryption file (e.g. video) in flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, encryption, stream

I want to download and encrypt a video. Then decrypt as a stream and play. But I could not find a suitable library.

Comment: Could you please extend your question with explanation of use case(file leakage) you are trying to prevent? Are you trying to make DRM system to prevent users of rooted devices to extract and redistribute files? If they have access to protected app folder then how do you plan to protect an encryption key then? Or do you try to protect private files to avoid leak in case of stolen device? - it is unlikely you could prevent leakage in case of "rooted" device or malware which uses 0day to elevate priviledges. And in case of "stolen device" the only way would be to ask user for password each time